# ModuleNotFoundError for all modules when importing into a python 3.8.2 environment on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip

When trying to access modules such as pandas, numpy, matplotlib etc. in a Python 3.8.2 Environment that I have downloaded (through pip install), I return a ModuleNotFoundError for all.

I had trouble accessing Python 3.8.2 on my Mac OSX and solved it by using homebrew to create a pyenv. I presume my current problem is not installing the modules into the correct Python environment.

This is the path that I am currently using for Python:

```
    /Users/myname/.pyenv/shims/python3
```

When I go pip install pandas for example in the terminal I receive:

```
    Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.3).
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I have very little experience with solving path problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mismatch between python version running in jupyter and python version running in terminal, if you are going to stick to pyenv, close all terminal window, open a new one, close all python services running and uninstall current python version:

```
pkill -f python
pyenv uninstall 3.8.2
```

And then:

```
pyenv install 3.8.2
pyenv local 3.8.2
pip install jupyter
pip install numpy
jupyter notebook
```

And try importing the packages from jupyter. Also make sure in your terminal `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bash_profile` have the following line `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately that did not solve the problem. pyenv local was already set to 3.8.2.

Comment: Run from jupyter: `!pip --list` and from the terminal `pip list` both output should contain the packages you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah both outputs show the same versions of the packages.

Comment: Run the following on jupyter it will list all modules that available from the kernel `help("modules")` and check if numpy, pandas, and matpplotlib are available.

Comment: Yeah, none of them are available.

Comment: Can you please print the version of python that is running? `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)`

Comment: I return:3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]

Comment: I am sorry to keep asking question just trying to understang where the error is, can you from the terminal do: `pyenv local 3.8.2` then `python` and then from the python terminal `import numpy as numpy`

Comment: No worries, I appreciate you taking the time to work it out! The first part returned Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 29 2020, 18:05:51) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)] on darwin. The second worked in the python terminal.

Comment: What about the `help('modules')` from the terminal?

Comment: All modules appear in the python terminal. So there is obviously a problem between jupyter notebook and the python terminal. Any ideas?